# URDF file parsing error in drake. Actuators not being instantiated

Tags: drake

I have been trying to setup a basic Pick n Place task using the template tutorial code provided. I am able to load the nextage robot by trying to load an existing `urdf` and mesh file. I am able to visualise the loaded scenario (robot, table and a cube) on meshcat. However, when I plug in all the necessary systems in a diagram for Pick'n Place(along with the Inverse Dynamics Controller, Trajectory Source etc.) I get the following error.

```
Failure at systems/controllers/inverse_dynamics_controller.cc:41 in SetUp(): condition 'num_positions == num_actuators' failed.
```

I had initially tried the same setup with the `PidController` class (instead of the inverse dynamics controller). My code had silently failed at the same point. There was a runtime error of the input/output port size mismatch between controller output and plant actuation input.

Which leads me to believe that there some crucial information in my URDF (num of actuators I guess) that `drake` is unable to find.

Any idea of what I may be missing?

**EDIT**: Please find the concerned `urdf` file being loaded under [this gist](https://gist.github.com/Kzernobog/d11de2de0012557d96f3a3526f4b637c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URDF file you posted does not have any http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/XML/Transmission elements defined with an `<actuator>` sub-element.  Drake's URDF parser only adds joint actuators when a transmission is defined.

The original [here](https://github.com/tork-a/rtmros_nextage/blob/indigo-devel/nextage_description/urdf/NextageOpen.urdf) does have transmissions and actuators, so somewhere along the way it looks like they got deleted.

See https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/master/manipulation/models/franka_description/urdf/panda_arm.urdf an example with transmissions.  (There's a lot of other sample URDFs elsewhere in ROS too.)

I don't know yet whether this is a bug in Drake (incorrect parsing assumptions) or a bug in the URDF file (missing data).  I will try to figure out whether URDF joints without a transmission are supposed to be actuated or not.

See https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/19136 for tracking and updates.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. A noob question here. The original nextage description has declared a `xacro` variable for the transmission and `<actuator>`. Does drake automatically parse this, or should I be compiling the xacro elements in the original `urdf` into a separate `urdf`?

Comment: At the moment, Drake doesn't know how to run Xacro automatically.  You should run Xacro yourself to create an URDF, and then tell Drake to load that.

Comment: Of all the discussions here, I think this answer is probably the "right" one. Could you "accept answer" in StackOverflow so this one moves up to the top of the list?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use the `MultibodyPlant` which has the robot + the table + the cube in the controller, that isn't going to work. You don't have enough actuators to directly control the cube.

I suspect what you want is to have a different `MultibodyPlant` with only the robot in it, which you should use for control. I call that the `controller_plant` in my example code. This is equivalent to the internal model that the robot control software holds (which doesn't know anything about the cube).  You can see an example of this in the [MakeManipulationStation](https://github.com/RussTedrake/manipulation/blob/396fe7c40b5881a58bbb5b8f083b70c1c11bd94f/manipulation/scenarios.py#L624) code I use in my [course notes](https://manipulation.mit.edu).

See our parallel conversation [here](https://github.com/RussTedrake/manipulation/issues/232).

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I am using as my template code. I have setup a default plant and a controller plant for the robot. The only difference is that instead of piping the [output port of the controller](https://github.com/RussTedrake/manipulation/blob/396fe7c40b5881a58bbb5b8f083b70c1c11bd94f/manipulation/scenarios.py#L758) to the `adder` (which pipes it to actuation port of robot+table+cube `plant`), I directly port it to the robot+table+cube plant actuation. Is that a mistake?

Comment: It would be safer to connect the controller to `plant.get_actuation_input_port(model_instance= nextage_instance)`, but I doubt that you have other actuators?

Comment: fwiw -- i've opened an [issue](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/19120) and a [PR](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/pull/19121) to see if we can help people through this a bit better.

Comment: Yes, I did the same. I connected the output port as the following
`builder.Connect(nextage_controller.get_output_port_control(), plant.get_actuation_input_port(nextage_instance)`. I am still getting the same error. Let me print out the actuated names vs. joint names as you have mentioned in your next comment.

Comment: Haha, the parallel conversation was with me.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend printing the joints names and actuator names for your plant/controller_plant?  Something like

```
    joint_names = [
        joint.name()
        for joint in [
            controller_plant.get_joint(JointIndex(i))
            for i in range(controller_plant.num_joints())
        ]
    ]
```

and the actuated joint names

```
    actuated_joint_names = [
        plant.get_joint_actuator(ind).joint().name()
        for ind in plant.GetJointActuatorIndices(model_instance)
    ]
```

Comment: Ok this is funny, the `controller_plant` says it has the following: `joint names: ['base_to_dummy', 'base_to_waist', 'CHEST_JOINT0', 'HEAD_JOINT0', 'HEAD_JOINT1', 'LARM_JOINT0', 'LARM_JOINT1', 'LARM_JOINT2', 'LARM_JOINT3', 'LARM_JOINT4', 'LARM_JOINT5', 'RARM_JOINT0', 'RARM_JOINT1', 'RARM_JOINT2', 'RARM_JOINT3', 'RARM_JOINT4', 'RARM_JOINT5', 'world_welds_to_base_link']
`. However, the `plant` says that it does not have the attribute `GetJointActuatorIndices`

Comment: I tried seeing if I am using a deprecated function from an older library, doesn't look like it.